# Dygraphs equivalent for GViz setVisibleChartRange?

Tags: google-visualization, dygraphs, annotatedtimeline

On our website http://tradingderivatives.eu/DAX-root.html, you can select a part of the tables and the graph will respond by zooming; the table event handers call the setVisibleChartRange method of the graph. Is there something similar for the graphs by Dygraphs?

I tried,among others, to google for "setVisibleChartRange Dygraphs" but nothing useful appears.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do this by calling [`updateOptions`](http://dygraphs.com/jsdoc/symbols/Dygraph.html#updateOptions). If you want to set the y-axis range, set [`valueRange`](http://dygraphs.com/options.html#valueRange). If you want to set the x-axis range, use [`dateWindow`](http://dygraphs.com/options.html#dateWindow):

```
g.updateOptions({
  dateWindow: [minDateInMillis, maxDateInMillis],
  valueRange: [yAxisMin, yAxisMax]
});
```

Comment: Thank you! It works! It is now all over our web page. I have posted another question on Dygraphs a while ago... It is about normalizing the data to the oldest date visible. That would be an extremely cool feature. Can you check it out? Thanks!